# Can I publically share code on Github for a website created for a company

Tags: united-kingdom, contracting, security

I've been asked to create a website (shop-front) for a local company, now that it's done they have allowed me to share a link to my personal portfolio.

The repository is currently private, but if possible I would like to either make it public, or on my portfolio - add a link and description to BOTH the website and the code repository.

I'm relatively close to the owners, so I'll certainly ask permission but is there a security risk to doing something like this?

All of the hosting details are obsfucated & my plan was to archive the original repository, clone it and push 1 commit to a new public repository to ensure any nefarious information from commit history should be removed (eg, `.env` files etc)

Appreciate any advice

Comment: I'm VTCing this, at best, this belongs in another Stack Exchange - one either about Cyber Security or Development - I don't think there is a 'Workplace' question here.

Comment: If you open up the code causing a vulnerability to be found and exploited, who will then pay for cleaning up the damages?  You'd better get permission.

Comment: No, absolutely no! You have given the source code at least to the github. But that is not yours, that is of the company. The rule of thumb: no bit of company data can leave the company network without a boss permission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question isn't so much about the security of the website but rather the ownership of the code. What does your contract say about who owns the code you've produced for this website? If you retain ownership and copyright of the code, then you can probably make the source available. If, as part of the transaction, the shop/company owns the code, then they get to make the decision. This *probably* should have been sorted out before you started writing any code.

You better be **very** certain that you're not publishing a "how to compromise this website" tutorial by posting the code publicly.

Any answer you get from the shop owners, make sure you have it in writing. And find out what happens if the store changes ownership and the new owner changes their mind about the code being available in the future (IOW, can they ask you to take it off your Github profile)

Comment: Hi @alroc - I'll admit the ownership of the code isn't something I considered when drawing up the contract. It seems the value of sharing the repository is outweighed quickly by potential copyright or compromising the website. I think I'll just add a link to the site on my portfolio and add a description rather than make the code public. Thank you!!

Comment: Even if you don't deliberately publish enough to make the site compromisable, it's a very easy mistake to include a live key somewhere, and even if you don't make that mistake the finger of suspicion will be on you if the site is ever compromised.

Answer (score 3):

Opinion: I would not share a repository containing a code base built for a client. My contracts with clients state that the total code base belongs to them. However, it is built on code modules that I own and have given them the right to use. I have the right to put those code modules into a repository that could be public.

A better solution for you might be to build a different shop-front for a mythical client and put that into a public repository.

Comment: I like this idea of a mythical shop. Certainly tweaks would be required, but it's a relatively simple step to take and is a best of both worlds without compromising the integrity of their site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A website is non-tangible or intellectual property. Depending on how you worded the sales pitch the client may understand that the website is theres now.

In my personal web development work I make it clear to clients that they can employ me to make them a website. I can host it for them, do a webmaster service or I can do the work provide the source code and they never have to see me again.

I do add it that I reserve the right to be credited as the creator / author and use a backdoor link in the footer to my website.

I wonder why you feel the need to have a repo of a website that is on the internet? Why not just show people the website?

But people bought it from you. The website should be theirs. There may also be issues with Github terms of service if you publicly share a code base that you don't own.